# Upgrading Windows Server 2008 r2 to Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

We are upgrading from Windows Server 2008 r2 to Windows Server 2012 r2.

Can we use the existing Windows Server 2008 r2 valid security certificate and the 30 remote desktop (RRAS/Terminal Services) CALS?

Will the CAL and certificate transfer during the upgrade? If not, where can I go to export the correct security certificate and Remote Access CALS?

Thank you so kindly for your feedback.

Jack

Comment: No;  Your CAL is for Windows Server 2008 R2 not Windows Server 2012 R2.  Your security certificate could b easily transferred.  "If not, where can I 
go to export the correct security certificate" - Certificate Manager (aka Certificate Store) and export it like any other certificate on the machine

Answer (score 2):

From
[Windows Server 2012 Licensing & Pricing FAQ](https://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0014/6695/WS2012_Licensing-Pricing_FAQ.pdf) :

> **Q28. Can I use my Windows Server 2008 CAL to access Windows Server 2012?**
>
> No. The CAL accessing the instance of Windows Server must be
>   equivalent or higher in version than the server being accessed. You
>   will need a Windows Server 2012 CAL to access a Windows Server 2012
>   instance.

This means that Windows Server 2012 CALs maybe could be used in
Windows Server 2008, but not the other way
(if they are still compatible).

The only way you could upgrade the CALs is via Software Assurance,
which I assume you do not have.